# How to enforce constraints on matrix equations for unknowns to have only one non zero element per row?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, constraint

I am trying to find a nice and efficient way to approach the following problem:
I need to solve (for example using Solve, Reduce, or NSolve) certain type of equations involving a set of unknown square matrices, which have at most one non-zero element in each row and the sum of the $j$-th row across all matrices is equal to one. In other words, the unknown matrices have at most one most non-zero element in each row and the sum of the matrices is a row-stochastic matrix. How can I tell Mathematica to look only for these type of solutions?

Any ideas on how to elegantly enforce such constraints? Can I tell Mathematica in advance that the unknown matrices can only have one non-zero element on each row?

Comment: Can you provide some code and the objective function you're trying to minimize / solve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Consider the long matrix `mat` formed by concatenating these horizontally. Then for all `{i,j}` you want to constrain `0<=.mat[[i,j]]<=1` and also `Total[mat[[i]]]==1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T = {{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}};

(* Takes a list of matrices,
   must be an equation with == sign and must return True/False *)
equation[matrices_] := KroneckerProduct[T[[1]], matrices[[1]]] == KroneckerProduct[T[[2]], matrices[[2]]]

(* ensures rows have at most one non-zero element *)
mostonehot[row_] := Max[row^2] == Total[row^2]

(* the one-hot constraint but for all rows of a single matrix *)
sparsecons[mtx_] := AllTrue[mtx, mostonehot]

(* row-stochastic matrix constraint, so all rows should add to 1 *)
stochasticcons[mtx_] := Total[Transpose@mtx] == ConstantArray[1, Length@mtx]


matrices = Array[a, {2, 3, 3}]; (* e.g a list of 2 3x3 matrices *)
sol = First[matrices /. FindInstance[
    (* our equation must hold *)
    equation[matrices] &&
     (* sum of matrices must be row-stochastic *)
     stochasticcons[Total[matrices]] &&
     (* all matrices must have one-hot rows *)
     AllTrue[matrices, sparsecons]
    , Variables[matrices], NonNegativeReals]]

(** RESULT (no solution)
{{a[1, 1, 1], a[1, 1, 2], a[1, 1, 3]}, {a[1, 2, 1], a[1, 2, 2], 
  a[1, 2, 3]}, {a[1, 3, 1], a[1, 3, 2], a[1, 3, 3]}} **)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is more or less what I was looking for. I will accept shortly. I have a question though. I tried to look for a solution to an equation that I suspect does not have one and instead of getting the empty set as a response, I get back the first row of each of the unknown matrices "matrices"(in your code) which I am not sure how to interpret.  What does such a response mean?

Comment: @AG1123 you may need to provide the equation in an edit to your question. `equation[...]` must return `True` or `False`. If it's returning anything else then something is broken.

Comment: Let ````T={{{1,0},{0,0}},{{0,0},{0,1}}}```` and 
````equation[matrices_]:= KroneckerProduct[T[[1]], matrices[[1]]]==KroneckerProduct[T[[2]], matrices[[2]]]```` which when combined with the constraints clearly has no solution. However, when I run your code for two $2\times 2$ matrices I get back ````{{a[1, 1, 1], a[1, 1, 2]}, {a[1, 2, 1], a[1, 2, 2]}}````.

Comment: @AG1123 that means there's no solution - if you remove the bit with `First[matrices /. ` and just look at the output for `FindInstance` it gives an empty list - it's the replacement I've done that puts those symbols appearing in the result.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense. Thanks!